# Android WebView to work with QUIC

Tags: android, webview, udp, quic

I am playing a YouTube video on a Android WebView and need it to work with QUIC protocol. Up until now I can only see TCP packets but no UDP.

- When I play a video in YouTube's app it works with QUIC.
- Chrome app also work with QUIC.
- I have tried this both on Android N & O.

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own question... as of yet it QUIC is not enabled in Android WebView.

There is an [open issue](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=763187) in Chromium.